# Generating responsive image html with php?

Tags: beginner, php, html, image

As a beginner in php, I welcome you feedback on improving or simplifying the following php code that generates this responsive image html (image sizes and formats are auto-generated using Gulp). For example, is having three nested foreach loops bad practice?

Generated HTML:

```
<figure>
    <picture>
        <source media="(orientation: portrait)" type="image/avif"
            srcset="assets/img/faith/faith-3x4-xs.avif 576w, assets/img/faith/faith-3x4-sm.avif 768w, assets/img/faith/faith-3x4-md.avif 992w, assets/img/faith/faith-3x4-lg.avif 1200w, assets/img/faith/faith-3x4-xl.avif 1400w, assets/img/faith/faith-3x4-xxl.avif 2048w">
        <source media="(orientation: portrait)" type="image/webp"
            srcset="assets/img/faith/faith-3x4-xs.webp 576w, assets/img/faith/faith-3x4-sm.webp 768w, assets/img/faith/faith-3x4-md.webp 992w, assets/img/faith/faith-3x4-lg.webp 1200w, assets/img/faith/faith-3x4-xl.webp 1400w, assets/img/faith/faith-3x4-xxl.webp 2048w">
        <source media="(orientation: portrait)" type="image/jpg"
            srcset="assets/img/faith/faith-3x4-xs.jpg 576w, assets/img/faith/faith-3x4-sm.jpg 768w, assets/img/faith/faith-3x4-md.jpg 992w, assets/img/faith/faith-3x4-lg.jpg 1200w, assets/img/faith/faith-3x4-xl.jpg 1400w, assets/img/faith/faith-3x4-xxl.jpg 2048w">
        <source media="(orientation: landscape)" type="image/avif"
            srcset="assets/img/faith/faith-3x2-xs.avif 576w, assets/img/faith/faith-3x2-sm.avif 768w, assets/img/faith/faith-3x2-md.avif 992w, assets/img/faith/faith-3x2-lg.avif 1200w, assets/img/faith/faith-3x2-xl.avif 1400w, assets/img/faith/faith-3x2-xxl.avif 2048w">
        <source media="(orientation: landscape)" type="image/webp"
            srcset="assets/img/faith/faith-3x2-xs.webp 576w, assets/img/faith/faith-3x2-sm.webp 768w, assets/img/faith/faith-3x2-md.webp 992w, assets/img/faith/faith-3x2-lg.webp 1200w, assets/img/faith/faith-3x2-xl.webp 1400w, assets/img/faith/faith-3x2-xxl.webp 2048w">
        <source media="(orientation: landscape)" type="image/jpg"
            srcset="assets/img/faith/faith-3x2-xs.jpg 576w, assets/img/faith/faith-3x2-sm.jpg 768w, assets/img/faith/faith-3x2-md.jpg 992w, assets/img/faith/faith-3x2-lg.jpg 1200w, assets/img/faith/faith-3x2-xl.jpg 1400w, assets/img/faith/faith-3x2-xxl.jpg 2048w">
        <img src="assets/img/faith/faith-3x2-lg.jpg" width="1200" height="800" alt="Earth Day, Victoria, BC">
    </picture>
</figure>
```

Php code:

```
 <?
$image= [
    'name' => 'faith',
    'srcset' =>
        [
        'sizes' =>
                [
                'size' => ['xs','sm','md','lg','xl','xxl'],
                'vw' => [ 576, 768, 992, 1200, 1400, 2048 ]
                ],
        'ratio' => ['portrait' => '3x4','landscape' => '3x2' ],
        'format' => ['avif', 'webp','jpg']
        ],
    'caption' => 'Earth Day, Victoria, BC',
];

$sizes = array_combine($image['srcset']['sizes']['size'], $image['srcset']['sizes']['vw']);
?>

 <figure>
     <picture>
         <?
        foreach ($image['srcset']['ratio'] as $orientation => $ratio):
        $basePath = "assets/img/{$image['name']}/{$image['name']}-{$ratio}";
            foreach($image['srcset']['format'] as $format): $comma = '';
            $source = "<source media=\"(orientation: ${orientation})\" type = \"image/{$format}\" srcset=\"";
                foreach($sizes as $size => $vw):
                $source .= "{$comma}{$basePath}-{$size}.{$format} {$vw}w"; $comma=', ';
                endforeach;
            echo $source .= '">';
            endforeach;
        endforeach;
        ?>
         <img src="<?=$basePath?>-lg.jpg" width="1200" height="800" alt="<?=$image['caption']?>">
     </picture>
 </figure>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I don't like that much logic in the template. Even hate it. The code becomes unreadable. In such a case I would rather move all this intricate logic into the PHP part, doing some preprocessing that will result in the plain array, so the end code would be like this

```
<figure>
    <picture>
<?php foreach ($image['srcset'] as $row): ?>
        <source media="(orientation: <?=$row['orientation']?>)" type="image/<?=$row['format']?>" srcset="<?=$row['srcset'] ?>">
<?php endforeach ?>
        <img src="<?=$imagePath?>lg.jpg" width="1200" height="800" alt="<?=$image['caption']?>">
    </picture>
</figure>
```

The preprocessing PHP code should be exactly like your current code, just collecting the data into array instead of echoing it

```
$new = [];
foreach ($image['srcset']['ratio'] as $orientation => $ratio) {
    $basePath = "assets/img/{$image['name']}/{$image['name']}-{$ratio}";
    foreach($image['srcset']['format'] as $format) {
        $srcset = '';
        foreach($sizes as $size => $vw) {
            $srcset .= $srcset ? ",":"";
            $srcset .= "{$basePath}-{$size}.{$format} {$vw}w"; 
        }
        $new[] = [
            'orientation' => $orientation,
            'format' => $format,
            'srcset' => $srcset,
        ];
    }
}
```

another possibility is to write sort of a helper function

```
<figure>
    <picture>
        <?php foreach ($image['srcset']['ratio'] as $orientation => $ratio): ?>
            <?php foreach($image['srcset']['format'] as $format): ?>
                <source media="(orientation: <?=$orientation?>)" type="image/<?=$format?>" srcset="<?=getsrcset($image, $ratio, $format, $key)">
            <?php endforeach ?>
         <? endforeach ?>
         <img src="<?=$imagePath?>lg.jpg" width="1200" height="800" alt="<?=$image['caption']?>">
     </picture>
</figure>
```

And two generic suggestions:

- short open tag is forbidden, always use `<?php` instead of `<?`
- do not neglect the code indentation. The proper formatting is very important, it helps to understand what does the code do

Comment: Thanks for your detailed feedback!

Comment: Just use your two nested loops but not to generate HTML, but to create a 1-level array. It should be quite the same.

Comment: Ping me If you don't manage, I'll get you a sketch

Comment: I already added it, not tested tho

Comment: Works great. I just had to change "<?php foreach ($image['srcset'] as $row): ?>", in our original answer ("end code"), to your $new array, "<?php foreach $new as $row): ?>. Thanks again. I learnt a lot from your answer.

Comment: Also, since you came up  a more elegant way to add commas, the $srcset .= "{$comma}{$basePath}-{$size}.{$format} {$vw}w"; can be edited  down to $srcset .= "{$basePath}-{$size}.{$format} {$vw}w";